# What might the forward voltage and current rating of this LED lamp be?

Tags: led, identification

I bought the following 3-LED lamp over 10 years ago. I want to use it in a project now, but I don't have the original packaging/information and it has no visible product numbers or specs inside or out. I removed the reflective shroud and glassy case covering the LEDs with no luck, only revealing a couple PCBs, a capacitor and an inductor, etc. The LEDs' PCB has wide traces and it is mounted on a heat sink. Does anyone have a guess as to the forward voltage and current rating, or know where else I could find more information?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: That PCB is for sure an LED driver. Hook it up to your lab power supply and raise the voltage until it doesn’t get any brighter. That’s your minimum operating voltage. As for maximum, that’s harder to tell. Can you read and part numbers off the components on it?

Comment: I'd guess that it expects a 12 volt supply, since it looks like it could be an automotive light.

Comment: PCB might be current stabilizer. Input is not polarized, since it has diode bridge. Diodes look like 1W each. So voltage can be 4-20V, AC or DC. Wattage 3W. PCB inside may create some blinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a 3 LED lighthead, commonly used on things like emergency vehicles and tow trucks. It should be 12V, current would be somewhere between 1/2 A to maybe 2 A, white wire positive. It's hard to say the exact model as there are a number of manufacturers that make them.

The wire color often denotes the LED color, so it might be white LEDs. They also come in red, blue, amber and ones where you can switch colors. Some have flash patterns built in, but those would have a third wire. I would suspect this one is just a steady white light.

Don't look at them when you power them up, they'll be very bright.